# Inequality base SQL base on other SELECT parameters

Tags: google-bigquery

This is to do cascade inequality based constraints SQL in Big Query.
date1 is used as intermediate parameter.

```
Select  id, date, date1
 From   table1
 Where  date > date1  
        AND date1 in ( select dateref from table2)
```

In Loop version:

```
For all date1 in (select dateref from table2) :
   select id, date, date1
   from table1 
   where date > date1
```

Answer (score 0):

One special case solution in case of other people looking for.
JOIN can be used to align the two tables, if they share same id.

```
select  same_id, date1,  dateref 

from ( 
   select   g1.same_id,  date1,  g2.dateref  
   from   `log2*`   as g1
   JOIN
      (  
        select  dateref,
          from `log1*`
          WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170630'
      )   as g2
      ON   g1.same_id = g2.same_id  


where
     _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170630'
)
where 
      date1 > dateref
```